# Confounded logging, missing application log messages - AWS EMR, spark-submit, yarn cluster mode, log4j

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I am running a spark-submit (version 3.2.1-amzn-0) job that executes Scala code (`RandomForest`) we've written on Amazon EMR 6.7.

```
spark-submit ... --class ...RandomForest \
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties" \
 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties" \
 --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn ...
```

We are trying to debug some problems by using log4j v1 to print various bits of information. We do not see our log4j log messages, but do see some `println` statements that we've interspersed. Here's the relevant code:

```
object RandomForest extends Serializable {
    val logger: Logger = LogManager.getLogger("gov.afms.dbp.spark.analytics.RandomForest")
// ...
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("println before 1st log statement")
        logger.info("RandomForest start...")
        println("println before 2nd log statement")
        logger.fatal("RandomForest start (not really fatal)...")
        println("println says... RandomForest after log statements")
```

The relevant part of `loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties` looks like this:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,rolling,console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, rolling 

log4j.appender.rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.conversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n 
log4j.appender.rolling.maxFileSize=100MB 
log4j.appender.rolling.maxBackupIndex=10 
log4j.appender.rolling.file=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/biobank_1_2.log 
log4j.appender.rolling.encoding=UTF-8
```

I collect the various logs from yarn using:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_168... > all.logs
```

The `stdout` part of `all.logs` contains our `printlns` but not any of our log4j messages.

```
========================================================================================================
LogType:stdout
LogLastModifiedTime:Thu May 25 17:12:28 +0000 2023
LogLength:7256
LogContents:
println before 1st log statement
println before 2nd log statement
%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%nprintln says... RandomForest after log statements
```

It appears that our `loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties` file is being read, because I see lines mentioning biobank_1_2.log in `all.logs`, and that could only come from `loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties`:

```
End of LogType:biobank_1_2.log
```

although I don't see any lines indicating the start of `biobank_1_2.log`, and I don't see the output of the "fatal" log statement.  Why don't I see the output of the "fatal" log message anywhere in `all.logs`?  One thing I find weird is that EMR's [Configure cluster logging and debugging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html) mentions 4 logs that get collected but doesn't say anything about the application's log.

Comment: Perhaps you can add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` into your spark.xxxxx.extraJavaOptions and see if log4j is able to properly load your config.

Comment: @mazaneicha - Good suggestion.  It does look like my log4j configuration file is being read properly.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try distributing the file with Log4j properties to the cluster using the `--files` argument and, in the case you're using Log4j 1, prefix the properties file's path with `file:`?

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client\
 --class app.App\
 --files loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties\
 --conf 'spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:loggingSparkSubmitlog4j1.properties'\
 --conf 'spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/tmp/spark_app/'\
 target/scala-2.12/test-app_2.12-1.0.jar 

Message from the println().
Message from the System.err.println().
logger.isInfoEnabled() = true
23/06/16 17:13:53 INFO RandomForest: Message from logger.info().
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I do use the --files argument.  We retrieve from S3 with "--files "s3://ourbucket/somepath/loggingSparkSubmitLog4j1.properties" and that file does appear to get downloaded and used.